# How to iterate a function a certain number of times based on a given value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe `df` that has one column `x` and three rows:

```
    x
0   3
1   5
2   2
```

I want to iterate an arithmetic operation (10*2 for example) a certain number of times on each row, depending on the value of `x` in the row.

For example, my expected output is as follows:

```
    x   x_0   x_1   x_2   x_3   x_4
0   3   20    20    20    nan   nan
1   5   20    20    20    20    20
2   2   20    20    nan   nan   nan
```

In the above output, multiplication has been iterated 3 times on first row as the value of `x` is 3 and so on.

I am using the below code to achieve my expected output:

```
for i in range(len(df['x'])):
    val_x_i = df['x'][i]
    for j in range(val_x_i):
        df['x_'+str(j)] = 10*2
```

However, the above code is resulting in following output:

```
    x   x_0   x_1   x_2   x_3   x_4
0   3   20    20    20    20    20
1   5   20    20    20    20    20
2   2   20    20    20    20    20
```

I assume `val_x_i = df['x'][i]` is resolving to the largest value of column `x`, which is 5, and hence the loop is executing 5 times on all the rows.

Appreciate any suggestion/ help in amending the code to get the expected output. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea with lambda function and loop by `df[x]` by [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df = df.join(df['x'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(20, index=range(x))).add_prefix('x_'))

print (df)
   x   x_0   x_1   x_2   x_3   x_4
0  3  20.0  20.0  20.0   NaN   NaN
1  5  20.0  20.0  20.0  20.0  20.0
2  2  20.0  20.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Your solution should be changed by [`Series.items`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.items.html) and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
for i, x in df['x'].items():
    for j in range(x):
        df.loc[i, f'x_{j}'] = 10*2
        
print (df)
   x   x_0   x_1   x_2   x_3   x_4
0  3  20.0  20.0  20.0   NaN   NaN
1  5  20.0  20.0  20.0  20.0  20.0
2  2  20.0  20.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Good use of f-string

Comment: @jezrael Second solution is working exactly as required. For my understanding, can you please explain the role of i here? Also, what is causing the loop to stop executing after the value of x in a row (which was missing in my code)?

Comment: @navi - `i` is index of DataFrame, it is used for distingush row by index. so it means first row loop by i for index and x for value of column `x` and in second loop is set each row by index i and new columns names from f-strings

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
import pandas as pd

df =pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 4]})

print(df)

def get_col(val):
    col_val = {}
    for i in range(val):
        col_val['x_'+str(i)] = 10*2
    return col_val

df = df.merge(df.x.apply(lambda s: pd.Series(get_col(s))), left_index=True, right_index=True)

print(df)
```

**output:**

```
   x
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  5
4  7
5  4
   x   x_0   x_1   x_2   x_3   x_4   x_5   x_6
0  1  20.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1  2  20.0  20.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2  3  20.0  20.0  20.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  5  20.0  20.0  20.0  20.0  20.0   NaN   NaN
4  7  20.0  20.0  20.0  20.0  20.0  20.0  20.0
5  4  20.0  20.0  20.0  20.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

create a new dataframe according to `x`'s values. then join to origin df.

```
dfn = pd.DataFrame(df['x'].map(lambda x:[2*10] * x).tolist())
print(df.join(dfn.add_prefix('x_')))

       x  x_0  x_1   x_2   x_3   x_4
    0  3   20   20  20.0   NaN   NaN
    1  5   20   20  20.0  20.0  20.0
    2  2   20   20   NaN   NaN   NaN
```